# Can we avoid database calls in a forEach loop in following scenario?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am developing a chat application. I am using Express JS and MongoDB in backend and Angular in frontend. I have 2 collections. One is **Users** and another is **ChatHistory** belwo are the schemas for each.

**For Users**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type: type.String, required: true},
    contact:{type: type.String, required: true},
    email:{type: type.String, required: true},
    password:{type: type.String, required: true},
    age:{type: type.Number, default:0},
    pic:{type: type.String, default:''},
    dob: {type:type.Date, default: ''},
    last_seen: {type:type.Date, default: ''},
    online_status: {type:type.String, default: 'offline'},
    show_last_seen: {type:type.Boolean, default: true},
})
```

**and For ChatHistory**

```
  const ChatHistorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        sender_id:{type: type.ObjectId, ref:'Usres', required: true},
        receiver_id:{type: type.ObjectId, ref:'Usres',required: true},
        message:{type: type.String,required: true},
        is_deleted:{type: type.Boolean,default:false},
        target_messages_id:{type:type.String,default:''},
        file_name:{type:type.String,default:''},
        message_read_status:{type: type.Boolean,default:false},
    })
```

I want to display the last received message and count of all unread messages for each user when I am showing the listing of users. So I am doing following way

```
 userList = await UsersCollection.find({},{name:1,email:1,online_status:1,last_seen:1,pic:1});
//getting all user list

  if(userList.length > 0){

// iterate over each user to get the last message and all unread messages count of each user 
    async forEach((obj)=>{

        await getLastMessage();
        await getAllUnreadMessageCount()

    })
  }
```

And I am getting the results. But like we all the know that hitting database in a loop is not a good idea. So I want to know that is there any other optimized way to do the same?
Would be a great help.

Comment: You can rewrite the `forEach()` with an aggregation pipeline that has two `$lookup` stages. It's not clear to me why the preceding `find()` (to get `userList`) doesn't have a filter applied to it though

Comment: There will be a filter. But my focus was on that database calls inside foreach

Comment: `$lookup` is the solution here, but we can't advise further unless we know how those two nested functions are finding/matching documents

Comment: @user20042973 can you guide me with that lookup query ?